# Energy Required to Rip Spacetime

Tags: gravity, spacetime, wormholes

I have heard that the presence of an extremely strong gravitational field possesses the capacity to warp or tear spacetime and to potentially create a wormhole.  Is any energy lost when spacetime is ripped? And if so, is there a constant energy per volume required to 'rip' a given region of spacetime?  Otherwise, is there some minimum gravitational field strength required to rip spacetime?

Comment: To make a calculation and give an answer, one would, I think, at least require a mathematical description of "rip a given region spacetime".

Comment: It sounds like you're referring to topology change. The classic paper on this topic is by Geroch, http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1967JMP.....8..782G . Here is a more recent discussion: http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9406053 . Geroch showed that there must be either CTCs or a violation of the weak energy condition.

Answer (score 1):

presumably a rip model would need a critical Riemann curvature above which general relativity breaks down as a description. General Relativity itself allows curvature to have arbitrary values. Black hole singularities in Classical GR have curvatures that diverge as we move closer to the singularity.

Some physicists expect that a quantum theory of gravity will predict some kind of softening of singularities, but this is speculative. There is no mainstream model of 'spacetime rips'.

In string theory and M-Theory, spacetime is allowed to be of high dimensionality, and it can contain defects that look like long strings or sheets, but these are conceptually closer to a twist in spacetime (just like a crystal dislocation). Again, these structures are highly speculative, but if they exist, they are expected to behave like magnetic monopoles

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a misunderstanding of vocabulary. Gravity is a curvature of space-time, not a rip.

A rip sounds like space is torn into two pieces with "nothing" in between. As if there was an edge to space. This does not happen.

No wormhole has ever been seen. If one was created, it would collapse before anything could get through it, even if traveling at the speed of light. But as long as it existed, there would be a path from one end to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Some theories do allow for "rips" in spacetime, usually some variants of quantum gravity which allow for topology change.

Such a concept goes back to Penrose's quantum foam concept, who theorized that high enough curvature might allow for a change in topology at the Planck scale level, though without much theoretical justification.

But for instance, if you use a path integral formulation of quantum gravity along with a sum over all topologies (or a particular class of topologies), you can get wormholes or other such structures naturally developing. The energy scale for such process are I think pretty much always on the Planck scale, though.

If you want to give it a read you can look up for instance Coleman's wormhole gas ideas.